# DIVI accordion have last item open

Tags: javascript, java, wordpress, accordion, divi

As the title states I'd like to always have the last item on the DIVI accordion module open by default. As I'm not good in coding JavaScript and I couldn't find anything helpful on the internet I thought I'd ask here for help.

At the moment I use this code but it's only closing all accordions.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var setState = "close";
    if(setState == "open"){
        jQuery(".module-akkrodion .et_pb_toggle").removeClass("et_pb_toggle_close");
        jQuery(".module-akkrodion .et_pb_toggle").addClass("et_pb_toggle_open");
        jQuery(".et_pb_toggle_open .et_pb_toggle_content").css("display", "block");
        jQuery(".et_pb_toggle_open .et_pb_toggle_title").addClass("all_on");
        jQuery(".all_on").on("click", function(){
            
            
            if(jQuery(this).parent().hasClass("et_pb_toggle_open")){
                jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("et_pb_toggle_open");
                jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("et_pb_toggle_close");
                jQuery(this).parent().css("padding", "20px");
                jQuery(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("et_pb_toggle_close");
                jQuery(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("et_pb_toggle_open");
                jQuery(this).parent().siblings().css("padding", "20px");
                
            }
          jQuery(this).removeClass("all_on");
        
            
        })
        
    }else{
        jQuery(".module-akkrodion .et_pb_toggle").removeClass("et_pb_toggle_open");
        jQuery(".module-akkrodion .et_pb_toggle").addClass("et_pb_toggle_close");
        jQuery(".et_pb_toggle_close .et_pb_toggle_content").css("display", "none");
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no JS expert but couldn't you add a css class and this class would use the :last-child pseudo class, set to display: none; ?

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately it didn't work but you gave me a good idea of a easy work around via css - will post my solution once I figured it out.